# BackgroundWorker - CancellationPending changing to false in RunWorkerCompleted. Why?

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

After canceling the BackGroundWorker, in the DoWork, the CancellationPending is true but when he comes to the RunWorkerCompleted, the CancellationPending is false. I dont know what did I do wrong?

```
static BackgroundWorker b1;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    b1=new BackgroundWorker();
    b1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(work1);
    b1.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(completed);
    b1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    b1.RunWorkerAsync("Hellow");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static void completed(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (((BackgroundWorker)sender).CancellationPending)
        Console.WriteLine("Canceled!");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Result:" + e.Result);//it goes here every time
}

private static void work1(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    ((BackgroundWorker)sender).CancelAsync();
    if (((BackgroundWorker)sender).CancellationPending)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

By the way, How can I add an error that occur in the DoWork to the RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs.Error for shoing it up to the user?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the CancellationPending property is for use during the background operation (in your work1 method).  It will tell the background worker that you have requested the background operation be canceled.  Once the RunWorkerCompleted event is called, the background worker has done the work to cancel the request, and therefore the cancellation is no longer pending.

EDIT: the RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs has a Cancelled property that will tell you if the background operation was cancelled.

If you throw an exception from the DoWork method (work1 in your case), it should be caught by the BackgroundWorker and populate the Error property of the RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs.

Comment: In each example online, they use CancellationPending in the RunWorkerCompleted to check if the bgw was canceled. Thank you for your time but you are incorrect.

Comment: Actually @brian s is correct. You need to check the Cancelled flag in the RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs parameter in your completed function.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.runworkercompletedeventargs.aspx

Comment: Yes, thank you @Surfbutler, I forgot about the Cancelled flag.

Comment: Ho! I got it, Thanks guys and im sory Brain S. Thank you agian.

Comment: No worries, if I'd have remembered the Cancelled flag, it wouldn't have been so confusing.  Glad you got it worked out.  I will edit the answer so as not to confuse others in the future.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, the BackgroundWorker class sets the CancellationPending property to false before raising the RunWorkerCompleted event.  Whether or not the worker was actually cancelled.

This is quite intentional, it stops you from falling into a nasty trap that's always around when you use threads.  Code that uses threads often misbehaves randomly and unpredictably due to a kind of bug called "threading race".  It is a very common kind of bug and dastardly difficult to debug.

What can easily go wrong in your intended approach if BGW didn't do this is that you'll assume that the worker got cancelled when you see CancellationPending set to true.  But that's an illusion, you cannot tell the difference between it being cancelled and it completing normally.  The corner case is you calling CancelAsync() a microsecond before the worker completes.  The worker never has a chance to even see the CancellationPending flag set to true, it was busy finishing the last bits of the DoWork event handler method.  That's a threading race, the worker raced ahead of your call and completed normally.

The proper hand-shake that avoids this bug is your worker setting e.Cancel to true when it sees the CancellationPending property set to true.  And of course stopping what's its doing.  Now it is reliable, the e.Cancelled property in the RunWorkerCompleted event handler is a copy of e.Cancel.  So your code can now reliably tell you whether or not the worker saw the cancel request.

Comment: if you pass your BackgroundWorker object around, you will also have to pass the DoWorkEventArgs with it to do what Hans is suggesting. I usually call BackgroundWorker worker and DoWorkEventArgs dwea - then I may have a context where I do: 


    `if(worker.CancellationPending){dwea.Cancel = true; return;}`