# Could the Cancel flag suffer from race-condition when stoping and restarting a BGWorker?

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, race-condition

I've seen this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11710652/2215451)

> Yes, the BackgroundWorker class sets the CancellationPending property to false before raising the RunWorkerCompleted event.

and the documentation of [CancelAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.cancelasync%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [RunWorkerAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h01xszh2(v=vs.110).aspx)

I have this code that prevents `InvalidOperationException` being thrown. It's my code, so `WorkerSupportsCancellation` is true.

```
public void Start()
{
    lock (OnOffLock)
    {
        if (worker.IsBusy)
            return;
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}
public void Stop()
{
    lock (OnOffLock)
    {
        worker.CancelAsync();
    }
}
```

I know that there is no way to avoid a posible race-condition happening if I call for CancelAsync while the worker is already stoping (for whatever reason). What I want to know for sure is something that it may be common sense, but it is not explained on the documentation.

When calling `RunWorkerAsync` (e.g. restarting the worker after an stop) it is `CancellationPending` set to false to avoid an unhandled cancel?

My guess is that when calling `RunWorkerAsync`, the `CancellationPending` flag is set to false no matter what was its previous value, but I didn't found confirmation on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this it's correct : [BackgroundWorker.cs](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/whidbey/REDBITS/ndp/fx/src/CompMod/System/ComponentModel/BackgroundWorker@cs/1/BackgroundWorker@cs)

```
public void RunWorkerAsync(object argument)
    {
        if (isRunning)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.GetString(SR.BackgroundWorker_WorkerAlreadyRunning));
        }

        isRunning = true;
        cancellationPending = false;

        asyncOperation = AsyncOperationManager.CreateOperation(null);
        threadStart.BeginInvoke(argument,
                                null,
                                null);
    }
```

Comment: This answer exactly my question :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is *very* strong race potential.  It can take a while for your RunWorkerCompleted event handler to start running, it depends on what your UI thread is doing.  It could be long done and you have no way to find out that it is done from the UI thread.  The reason that BGW resets CancellationPending, it doesn't tell you anything about what really happened.

You have to code this carefully so you can detect that it *actually* got cancelled.  Roughly:

```
    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
        (some-loop-construct) {
            if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending) {
               e.Cancel = true;    // Important!
               return;
            }
            // etc...
        }
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) {
        if (e.Error != null) {
            // Something bad happened
        }
        else if (e.Cancelled) {
            // It actually got cancelled
        }
        else {
            // It actually completed
        }
    }
```

Setting e.Cancel to true in your DoWork event handler is important, that's what sets e.Cancelled in your RunWorkerCompleted event handler

Comment: Oh man! One month and I didn't saw this... Anyway, because you answered a few hours before I confirmed a valid answer, you deserve a clarification =)
I was asking for a more precise scenario: Let's say that the code gets to the last else (It actually complete) AND a CancelAsync was called at the same time. I'm ok with the Cancel flag being ignored at this point. What I wanted to know for sure is what would happen when RunWorkerAsync is called again with Cancel set to true. As @Sievajet answered, it is set to false no matter what, so question answered.